Does the sign affect the precision and accuracy of floating point numbers?
In floating-point arithmetic, if two numbers have the same binary representation, then the result of any operation performed on these numbers should be the same, and equality comparisons using == should work as expected.
For example, if a and b are computed as 1.0/3.0, they will indeed have the same binary representation in a standard floating-point system. Therefore, x and y calculated as follows shall be identical and the assertion shall hold.
double a = 1.0/3.0;
double b = 1.0/3.0;
double x = a*a/Math::Pi;
double y = b*b/Math::Pi;
assert(x==y);

My question is, will the sign of the number affect the accuracy of the results? Will the following be always true?
double a = 1.0/3.0;
double b = -1.0/3.0;
double x = a*a/Math::Pi;
double y = -(-b*b/Math::Pi);
assert(x==y);

How about this? Will the assertion hold?
double a = 1.0/3.0;
double b = 1.0/7.0;
double x = a-b;
double y = -(b-a);
assert(x==y);

I mainly work on x86/x64 machines. I thought C/C++/ASM shall have the same behaviour, so I tagged both C and C++.

It depends on the rounding mode used.

Please don't tag irrelevant languages. (Fixed) /// And wouldn't that be dependent on the hardware? You didn't mention anything about that.

@WeijunZhou May I know what rounding mode is used in an x86/x64 CPU?

@zmz rounding mode can be configured live.

Floating point numbers in IEEE 754 are represented as sign-bit, exponent, mantissa. So, if all calculations differ only by sign bit the other bits should be identical for identical operations.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round

@Gene Not necessary, 1./3. and (-1.)/3. may not differ by the just the sign bit when for example the rounding is towards positive infinity. The rounding mode introduces an asymmetry.

I looked for information on this in the C++ standard, rather than IEEE-754, but cannot find where the C++ standard specifies a floating-point model. The C 2018 standard specifies a model in 5.2.4.2.2 3, that a floating-point number is defined by the model s•b^e•sum(f[k]•b^−k for k = 1 to p), from which we can see the represented numbers are symmetric with respect to the sign s. (Rounding modes introduce asymmetry, and loose specifications for converting text numerals to floating-point allow asymmetry.) Can anybody point to someplace in the C++ standard that specifies a similar model?

@EricPostpischil C++ section [numeric.limits.members] contains the footnote "lowest() is necessary because not all floating-point representations have a smallest (most negative) value that is the negative of the largest (most positive) finite value." So I think there is no intend to mandate a specific model

"and equality comparisons using == should work as expected." --> When the 2 values are NAN, the compare is false, even with same bit pattern.

As a demonstration of how the rounding mode can matter, consider this code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main()
{
    double a =  1.0 / 3.0;
    double b = -1.0 / 3.0;
    if(a != -b) printf("unexpectedly unequal #1\n");

    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);

    a =  1.0 / 3.0;
    b = -1.0 / 3.0;
    if(a != -b) {
        printf("unexpectedly unequal #2:\n");
        printf("a = % .20f\n", a);
        printf("b = % .20f\n", b);
    }
}

When compiled under clang v. 14.0.3 on my Mac (as either C or C++) this code does print "unexpectedly unequal #2",
with the values of a and b displayed as:
a =  0.33333333333333331482
b = -0.33333333333333337035

[In retrospect, I'm impressed this worked the way it did.  Either clang is declining to do floating point constant folding at compile time, or it is evaluating the effect of the fesetround call at compile time.]
[Note, too, that the change to the rounding mode has affected the way printf renders the numbers.  Under normal rounding, they would have been 0.33333333333333331483 and -0.33333333333333337034.]

Update: this example code does not work (does not print "unexpectedly unequal #2") under gcc, I suspect because gcc is going ahead and folding the constants at compile time.  Under gcc v. 13.1.0, at least, it suffices to create global variables double one = 1.0; and double three = 3.0; and then use one and three in the various computations of a and b.

Experimenting suggests once you use #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON, Clang stops evaluating floating-point expressions at compile time. Which is nice; years ago it used to ignore FENV_ACCESS.

@EricPostpischil Aha!  That's what I suspected, but I was too lazy to investigate.  Thanks for confirming.

TLDR: In theory the sign can affect results, in practice it doesn't.
The standard for floating point numbers is IEEE-754. It specifies that the sign is encoded in a separate bit. This means that, unlike with integers that use Two's complement, the range is exactly symmetrical around zero. Neither the significand nor the exponent are affected by the sign. Therefore the sign does not affect precision.
However, IEEE-754 allows different rounding modes to deal with the lowest bit in the significand (internally, the CPU computes with more bits, then rounds to the closest floating point representation). If you change the rounding mode to towards positive or negative infinity, this will affect results. But this is rarely (if ever) done and you have to opt-in to that behavior change; it is not the default.
Even if you write a library, it is probably easier to just mandate it being called with a standard math environment. Otherwise you may also have to worry about trapping math and signalling NaNs. Not every hardware implementation supports changing the rounding mode either, for example GPUs generally don't or only via explicit instructions (CUDA, OpenCL). Not caring about this is also in line with GCC's default behaviour:

Without any explicit options, GCC assumes round to nearest or even and does not care about signalling NaNs.

Strictly speaking, most languages do not require IEEE-754 for their floating point type. However, you will have a hard time finding a system in wide use that doesn't follow the standard. See also Why not use a two's complement based floating-point?
The expectation that the range is symmetrical is also baked in a lot of code, including standard libraries. For example C++ before C++11 had std::numeric_limits<float>::max() for the largest finite positive value and std::numeric_limits<float>::min() for the smallest nonzero, normalized, positive value. If you wanted the most-negative finite value, you had to negate the max().
This only changed in C++11 with std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() but it did not change for C itself, which uses the similar float.h macros. It also still leaves gaps, for example there is no direct way to retrieve the first normalized, negative number below zero. The standard expects you to simply negate min().

“But nobody ever does that” is excessive and false. There are people who do that.

The preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation is “significand.” “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Significands are arithmetic; adding to a significand adds to the represented value, as scaled by the exponent. Mantissas are logarithmic; adding to a mantissa multiplies the represented value.

@EricPostpischil thanks on the note regarding mantissa! Significand is not commonly used for this in my native German which makes it hard to remember. Regarding the rounding, do you have any example where this is done and for what reason?

Directed rounding modes can be used for interval arithmetic, aiding in mathematical proofs about bounds, and extended-precision calculations. These uses are rare because of the cost involved by implementing rounding method selection using a global register, which is not required by IEEE-754. HP had an architecture where the rounding method could be specified per-operation (including per SIMD lane), making it amenable to flexible uses.
